# Solve $7+ye^x-x^2y^2+y^3=0$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm able to find the solutions for y from online calculators like WolframAlpha, but I have not been able to find steps or even general guidelines on how to approach such a problem.

Comment: Are you aware of Cardano formulas for 3rd degree polynomials

Comment: No, I am not. I will take a look at them now.

Comment: [General solution to the cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients)

Comment: Take care that the number of real solutions depends on the value of $x$.